# How can I keep the buttons when the button is dragged or dropped jQuery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I am trying to generate new preset button when the button is dropped in the div call "timeslot", I don't know how to do that so I made an function call "init()" which is remove all the button in the list generate the all the new preset buttons. However this is not a good way to generate new button by removing all the buttons in the list and generate all buttons again. Following is my code.

HTML

style sheet for the timeslot

```
<style type="text/css">
.timeSlot{
width: 100%;
height: 3rem;
border: 1px solid rgb(131, 100, 100);
}
</style>
```

Main code for html I also use some styling(for buttons)from the bootstrap

```
<div class="timeSlot">
</div>
<div class="timeSlot">
</div>
<div class="timeSlot">
</div>

<div class="list">    
<input type="text" placeholder="Add New Events">
<div class="preset"><button class="add btn btn-primary"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Eat</button></div>
<div class="preset"><button class="add btn btn-success"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Workout</button></div>
<div class="preset"><button class="add btn btn-warning"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Sleep</button></div>
<div class="preset"><button class="add btn btn-info"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Laundry</button></div>
<div class="preset"><button class="add btn btn-dark"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>Study</button></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("button").draggable({cancel:false ,cursor: "crosshair", revert: "invalid"});
```

Input box generate new buttons by entering the text

```
$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event){
if (event.which === 13) {
    var todoText = $(this).val();
    $(this).val("");
    $(".list").append("<div class=\"preset\"><button class=\"add btn btn-secondary\"><span><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i></span> " + todoText + "</button></div>");
  $("button").draggable({cancel:false ,cursor: "crosshair", revert: "invalid"});
  }
  });
```

Initial function

```
function init(){
$(".list").find(".preset").remove();
$(".list").append("<div class=\"preset\"><button class=\"add btn btn-primary\"><span><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i></span>Eat</button></div><div class=\"preset\"><button class=\"add btn btn-success\"><span><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i></span>Workout</button></div><div class=\"preset\"><button class=\"add btn btn-warning\"><span><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i></span>Sleep</button></div><div class=\"preset\"><button class=\"add btn btn-info\"><span><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i></span>Laundry</button></div><div class=\"preset\"><button class=\"add btn btn-dark\"><span><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i></span>Study</button></div>");
$("button").draggable({cancel:false ,cursor: "crosshair", revert: "invalid"});}
```

Drop function

```
$(".timeSlot").droppable({ accept: ".add", 
drop: function(event, ui) {
console.log("drop");
               $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
         var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);      
         init(); 

            }, 
      over: function(event, elem) {
              $(this).addClass("over");
               console.log("over");
      }
            ,
              out: function(event, elem) {
                $(this).removeClass("over");

              }
                 });
```

So the problem is when I use the input to generate some new buttons, if I use any buttons to drop, rest of the new generate buttons disappear. I am looking for a way to keep the buttons(including the new generate buttons) when the button is being dragged in the list or drop in the div. Apparently, the initial function is not a good way to do that because there are some logic errors(new generate buttons disappear when the other button is dropped). Can anyone help me to figure it out?

Some small edit, so what I want is the list automatically generate same buttons when the same button is dragged or dropped. For example, when the "Eat" button is dragged or dropped in the timeslot box, the list automatically generates a new "Eat" button in the list so I can add the another "Eat" button in the timeslot box without typing Eat in the input to generate a "Eat" button.

Comment: Just to clarify, here is what I understood: you want to have an initial list of buttons and a way to add new custom buttons (using the input box). And you want to be able to drag buttons from the list and drop in the "time slot" box, without removing the other buttons from the list. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, but except without removing the other buttons, I want to still keep the same button that I drag and drop in the box which means when I drag and drop any buttons in the list, the list automatically generate the same button that I drag so I don't have to create the new buttons with same event again by using the input box.

Comment: I updated my code on the answer bellow. Take a look to see if that's what you needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple example for you here:

https://codepen.io/brunomont/pen/moqjaj

You don't need your `init()` function at all if you have the "starting default buttons" on the HTML already.

Another change was to set the option `revert: true` for the **draggable** object and, on drop, create a copy using `$.clone()`. This means that every button will always go back to its original position, but, if the button is dropped in the "drop area" it will create a clone before it goes back to the original position.

I used the clone to apply the CSS and other things you had, so you only modified the cloned object.

Also, just as a best practice, I changed your `<div class="list">` to `<div class="id">`. Since you are using a reference to that div on jQuery to add new buttons, it is better to use *ID* instead of *class* (unique reference).

PS: Since you are not saving your list anywhere, you will lose any custom buttons (added using the input box) on page reload.

---

### EXTRA

To remove the clone functionality from a copied button, you could add a "copy" class to the button copy and check that on the `drop` function, like this:

```
$(".timeSlot").droppable({ accept: ".add",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.draggable).hasClass('copy')){
            $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = $(this);
            $(dropped).css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
            var dropped = ui.draggable;
            var droppedOn = $(this);
            var newBtn = $(dropped).clone();
            $(dropped).draggable("option", "revertDuration", 0);
            $(newBtn).addClass('copy');
            $(newBtn).css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(dropped).draggable("option", "revertDuration", 500);
            }, 100);
            $("button").draggable({cancel:false ,cursor: "crosshair", revert: true});
        }
    }, 
    over: function(event, elem) {
        $(this).addClass("over");
        console.log("over");
    },
    out: function(event, elem) {
        $(this).removeClass("over");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, your method is really good but I want to make the button is draggable when the button is in the div. In addition, the clone method does not have really good looking on the timetable. I was trying to  generate the button by detecting the ui.draggable. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I try to make some change the revertDuration to make looks like generate automatically on the list. But is it possible to remove clone function to the button in the div?

Comment: Sorry, @CommanderTom, I don't think I am understanding...what do you mean with "make the button is draggable when the button is in the div"? And what look and feel are you expecting when you say "the clone method does not have really good looking on the timetable"? Maybe you have a mock design to share or a website doing something similar?

Comment: About the second comment, I updated the link again. I think that's what you wanted...

Comment: Here is a link of the mock design of my project :https://codepen.io/zeyingzhou/pen/drJLKj I see the update link and it works well! But is it possible to make the preset buttons order do not changed?

Comment: Oh, I see...well, that makes more sense. But I would never guess from the previous code :)

I think my answer here solves your original question, so I will keep that in case someone else comes to this thread in the future. Since you also have a codepen setup, I will make the changes there to keep the order as you asked. Just don't want to mix the topics here.

Comment: @CommanderTom, I will be offline for a couple hours. I updated my link to keep the order. Is not an elegant solution, but I think it is what you asked for...we can start a separate chat and I can help you with a more clean way to keep the order, which will require some extra work on the HTML as well. Hope that helps for now.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate that! This helps a lot! Is it possible to make the buttons in the timetable don't have the clone function just make it draggable?

Comment: The clone only happens when you drag a button from the original list. The buttons on the timetable don't clone. Maybe you can update your codepen with my code so I can take a look there as well...you have more functionality there that could be creating an undesired effect.

Comment: Yeah, I understand but I want to make the buttons can also be draggable between the timeslot. However, I don't want to make the buttons already on the timetable have the clone function just make it drag simply between the timeslot and I update my codepen with your code. https://codepen.io/zeyingzhou/pen/drJLKj

Comment: @CommanderTom just updated my answer with that functionality :)

Comment: That's pretty smart. I didn't even think about I can make the clone button have a different class name. Thanks for pointing that out. I find the clone object is difficult to be detected after is being dragged two times in the timetable. I mean when the clone object is dropped in the timeslot and drag to the another timeslot, after that,   the button cannot be dragged immediately. It takes about one or two seconds to be dragged. I kinda fully under stand your code but except the function setTimeout(). Can you explain it how it works?

Comment: And I also update your code in my codepen. https://codepen.io/zeyingzhou/pen/drJLKj?editors=1010

Comment: I tried to move the button in the timetable as you said, and it does take a second to be able to move it again. But I believe that is part of the *jQuery UI* library. The `setTimeout()` affects only the buttons in the original list, not the ones in the timetable.
I used the `setTimeout()` as a click solution. Since you wanted the button to show up again in the list (after the drop in the timetable), I temporarily change the `revertDuration` to 0, so it "looks like" the button was included in the list, but in reality it just moved back.

Comment: The `setTimeout()` then sets the `revertDuration` back to 500 (default value) so you cna have the animation again. You can play with that by removing the `setTimeout()` to see the effect. This was a quick solution to make the button go back to it's same position in the list. If we delete and append the button again, to keep the position you would need to have an array or some kind of "storage" system to remember which was the position of that button. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. If possible, can we start a seperate chat to talk about a different clean way to do this functionality that you mention before? Your solution helps me a lot and works well.

Comment: Sure! Just let me know the best way to contact you...I am not sure if it is possible to start a chat here on StackOverflow